# RSRuby: R window is closing

Tags: ruby, r

I have a problem.
I connected R to Ruby with RSRuby and tried to use it.
When I do it through irb, it works properly.
But when I'm trying to start it through usual ruby file, it closes.

```
 88 r = RSRuby.instance
 89 
 90 puts 'Started R...'
 91 
 92 input_paths = File.readlines("testpaths").map!{ |el| el.to_i }
 93 
 94 puts "Read file of size #{input_paths.size}..."
 95 
 96 r.plot(input_paths, :type => "h", :ylim => [600, 900])
```

Comment: sleep() helps, but it's not a proper problem solve...

Answer (score 0):

The two ways of the solution are:

1. Use sleep(time).
2. Use gets() before the end of the script.
3. Use some other way to pause the script before it is finished.